# getting text from edittext use button

Tags: android, url, button, android-edittext

i can get text from activity one, how i can get text and paste into my URL ?

activity one

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button tombol;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tombol=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tombol.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
        });
```

activity two

```
EditText et;
ImageView iv;

public Button tombol;
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

 loadGambar();


 private void loadGambar(){
try {
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    tombol = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    URL url = new URL (et.getText().toString());
    InputStream is =  (InputStream) url.getContent();
    Drawable gambar = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
    iv.setImageDrawable(gambar);
    is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 tombol=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
 tombol.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
     Intent intent=new Intent();
     setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
     finish();

 }
 });
 }
```

}

i can getting text from edit text after click button, how to fix it ?

i ready try using StartActivity, i just want to getting that text paste into activity two in-line

URL url = new URL (et.getText().toString());

Comment: what is your issue. Passing values from one activity to other or get text from textview

Comment: Please clarify your question, I do not understand <"I can getting text from edit text after click button, how fix it?">. 
But in case it helps your second question, pass on data from one activity to another by using this `intent.putExtra("nameForThisExtra", "string")` and receive it like this in the other activity `String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("nameForThisExtra");`

Comment: i want to show picture after input text as URL, but after input and click button image can't showing,

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
    intent.putExtra("URL", yoururlstring);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

    }
    });
```

use the above code in activity one to pass value from one acivity to other

in the activiy2 to get the sring use

```
String url= getIntent().getExtras().getString("URL");
```

Comment: but i have error code on  InputStream is =  (InputStream) url.getContent(); after change command

Comment: InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent() in which I think you are using String not URL....